# Bounce of PT out of sync on FC

Tags: pt, bounce, final, cut, sync

Hey guys,

I just send a bounce file i made on PT to the editor of this project and he says that at the end of the file the sync is out and gets worse and worse. I've checked my settings on my session setup and everything is ok. Have ever encounter such a problem? if so, how can it be solved?

Thanks in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 2):

Hi Marco,

Sounds like the famous FCP bug/feature... Details are here: http://duc.avid.com/showthread.php?t=212057

Basically if Final Cut's capture AND Sequence settings don't match, Final Cut will try and conform the audio, resulting in it going out of sync. The editor can either match up the two and then get a NEW copy of the file from you (make sure you send him a new copy...FCP "marks" the file once it's been imported as needing to be adjusted and will do it regardless) or you can use Sebsky Tools to ouput a Quicktime Movie at the right frame rate.

Comment: Thanks Sonsey. I talked to the editor and he says everyhting is ok